# Django escribir campos de formulario a mano en el archivo html

Tags: python, django, formularios

Soy nuevo en Django y todavía no entiendo del todo como comunicarme con los formularios para poder customizar la forma en que se muestran en el template. Por ejemplo, busco la forma de hacer algo como este codigo: acceder al campo del formulario para poder darle estilo. Todavía no se cual es el mejor approach para llevar a cabo una operacion así. Nota: estoy tratando de combinar con Bulma, de ahi la clase "input is-primary". Mas adelante tambien me gustaría entender como poder darle un poco de padding para poder ubicar el formulario en un area mas conveniente de la pantalla. Gracias.

forms.py

```
 from django import forms
    
    
    class Formulario_Cliente(forms.Form):
        nombre=forms.CharField(label="Nombre", max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"input is-primary"}))
        email=forms.EmailField(label="email")
```

formulario.html

```
{% block formulario %}
    {% csrf_token %}
    
    {%for field in formulario.fields%}
       {%if field==formulario.fields['nombre']%}
       {{formulario.fields['nombre']}}
       <input class: "input" type: "text" placeholder: "Ingrese su nombre completo>
    
        {%if field==formulario.fields['email']%}
           {{formulario.fields['email']
            <input class: " input" type: "text" placeholder: "Ingrese su email>
    
    
    
    {% endblock formulario %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una forma de renderizar el template de una forma un poco mas customizada.

```
{% block formulario %}
{% csrf_token %}
    
    {{ formulario.nombre.label_tag }}
    {{ formulario.nombre }}
    {{ formulario.nombre.help_text }}
    {% if formulario.nombre.errors %}
        {% for error in formulario.nombre.errors %}
            <strong class="has-text-danger">{{ error|escape }}</strong>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    {{ formulario.email.label_tag }}
    {{ formulario.email }}
    {{ formulario.email.help_text }}
    {% if formulario.email.errors %}
        {% for error in formulario.email.errors %}
            <strong class="has-text-danger">{{ error|escape }}</strong>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
            
{% endblock formulario %}
```

Si no, siempre esta la forma rápida

```
{{ formulario.as_p }}
```